# Neo4j Running Total

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I'm a totally newb to Neo4j and I want to create a running total for a matched set of nodes. Here's what I have

```
MATCH n RETURN REDUCE(shares = 1000, p IN COLLECT(n) | shares - p.shares)
```

This just decrements from shares and displays a single result however I'm expecting something like:

```
shares  total
100     100
100     200
100     300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but you need an `itemID` or similar on your nodes, to provide an ordering for them, otherwise you can't do the running total.   Here's how it can work:

```
MATCH (f:F) 
WITH f 
OPTIONAL MATCH (g:F) 
WHERE g.itemID<f.itemID 
RETURN f.itemID, f.shares, sum(g.shares) + f.shares 
ORDER BY f.itemID ASC;
```

Here, I'm assuming you have an `itemID` on each node.  This is necessary because if you don't know which nodes come before or are less than others, you can't compute the running total.  But if you do have a field like itemID, then you do an extra optional match for all those items where the itemID is less than the one you're looking at, then you sum up those shares.  This provides an accurate running total.

This isn't a very efficient query though, since you'll sum and keep re-summing.  Say you have 4 nodes; the first sums nothing.  The second sums one.  The third sums 2 (one for the second time).  The fourth sums three (one for the third time, one for the second time).  So that's a lot of extra work to do.

What we're doing here is a hack to get around not having a mutable variable value.  If I needed to do this query, I'd usually be doing it from java/javascript/python/whatever.   I'd probably just get the `shares` value and compute the running total myself outside of cypher.

Comment: Thanks this worked. The real problem is I'm trying to do the bin packing algorithm in neo4j. if I put the running total logic in my application layer I need to keep a transaction open over the network which I was hoping of not having to do.

Comment: I tested with 100,000 nodes and yes the performance is horrible I had to stop it :(

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/15827cby5m/calculating-running-sum#201508022iulgipztalzd4t3c5qbhjtv54) by [Mark Needham](http://grokbase.com/user/Mark-Needham/uGsFzzkMGBgEZCMkwR9eiY) with a different method:

```
WITH [100, 100, 100, 200, 300, 500] AS allShares
UNWIND RANGE(0, LENGTH(allShares)-1) AS idx
RETURN allShares[idx],
REDUCE(acc = 0,
       value in (allShares[idx] + allShares[..idx]) |
       acc + value) AS cumulative

- ==> +-----------------------------+
- ==> | allShares[idx] | cumulative |
- ==> +-----------------------------+
- ==> | 100 | 100 |
- ==> | 100 | 200 |
- ==> | 100 | 300 |
- ==> | 200 | 500 |
- ==> | 300 | 800 |
- ==> | 500 | 1300 |
- ==> +-----------------------------+
- ==> 6 rows
```

I haven't tested its performance on large datasets, but at first glance it looks like it would be significantly faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n:Item)
RETURN sum(n.shares) as sum, collect(n.shares) as shares
```